# Message display in JOptionPane is not correct on MAC's Retina display

Tags: java, macos, swing, jlabel, joptionpane

It's been a while now that I'm trying to figure out this problem.

Mixed style message (Non-bold text + bold text) has display problem in `JOptionPane`: last char gets overriden by the question. This happens no matter how wide the option pane is. If I remove bold text, the display is correct as you can see in the screen shots attached.

This is happening in Mac OS Sierra on a MacBookPro (Retina Mid 2012). On Windows and Linux, the display is correct.

Any hint will be much much appreciated.

Note: in `JOptionPane`, messages are displayed using `JLabel` components layed out in a `JPanel` that uses `GridBagLayout`. Just in case that info is important.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OptionPaneTest
{
    private static final String TITLE                 = "NTIW Application Management Platform";

    private static final String EXIT_MESSAGE_BOLD     = "<html>Exit <b>NTIW Application Management Platform</b>?</html>";
    private static final String EXIT_MESSAGE_NON_BOLD = "<html>Exit NTIW Application Management Platform?</html>";

    private static final String DONT_SHOW             = "Do not show this message again";

    public static final void main( final String[] pArgs )
    {
        final Object[] message = {
            EXIT_MESSAGE_BOLD,
            " ",
            DONT_SHOW,
        };

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null,
                                       message,
                                       TITLE,
                                       JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );
    }
}
```

screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The screenshots don't look like the standard macOS look and feel. What L&F are you using? The problem might be specific to that L&F.

Comment: Ok done, but it should be really simple to reproduce I think.

Comment: Your code example works perfectly fine on my Mac (macOS 10.12.6, Java 1.8.0_141). But it uses the default Look and Feel from the system, which is definitely different from your screenshots. So, the in my opinion, the problem is most likely with your special Look and Feel.

Comment: The default JOptionPane and default L&F does not provide this "Do not show again" functionality. As long as we don't know the exact code of this customized option pane, help is not really possible.